# vertically center div in fluid container only using HTML

Tags: html, center

I am creating a code and I can only edit the HTML not allowed to make changes in the CSS file. How can I align all the content in the div only in html?

Comment: Are you really asking how to set style not via css file? Have you even tried searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `style` attribute.
e.g.

```html
  <span style="position:absolute; top:10px; background-color:green;"></span>
```